# Is buffer always fixed blocks allocated by hardware manufacturer?

Tags: c++, buffer, hardware

I have been trying to understand how buffer is constructed? As I understand buffer is a hardware construct such as logic gates are (please correct me if I am wrong). So, I was wondering whether buffer is the location/block always fixed by hardware manufacturer or it could be any location reserved by the software/OS. I mean any buffer i.e. data buffer, cache buffer, etc.

Apologies if my question is bit vague. I am just trying to understand how buffer is implemented and at what level.

Comment: What buffer?  What hardware?  This isn't a programming question.

Comment: I meant data buffer. The place used to store some intermediate data

Comment: That's still very vague.  `char myBuffer[1024];` could be a buffer.  So could `char myOtherBuffer[2048];`  Neither of those are defined by any hardware manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A buffer is simply a temporary storage facility for passing data between subsystems. The nature of that buffer (and definition of subsystems) depends on how and where it is used.

Hardware (such as a CPU) may implement a memory cache which is a type of buffer. Being in hardware the size is pretty much fixed but the actual size depends on the hardware design.

(Generically) In software a buffer is typically a chunk of memory reserved by the application that is used to temporarily store data generated by a producer and passed to a consumer for processing. It can be a static (fixed) size or expanded/contracted dynamically. It really depends on the application needs and is defined by the developer/designer.

A buffer is typically used for passing data between software and hardware. The most familiar being I/O. Because I/O is typically slow, data is usually buffered in some way to allow the software to continue running without having to wait for the I/O subsystem to finish.

Comment: Thanks Dave. In this case, can I assume that CPU cache/buffer is provided by hardware? Does I/O buffer gets allocated by OS?

Comment: Yeah the CPU cache (if there is one... there usually is) is typically hardware. An I/O buffer could be managed by the OS, or the run-time libraries, or both. Note that these are just two examples of the many, many uses of buffers. `buffer` is a very generic term.